# How to delete specific row in excel using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

When i use this code it always getting error can you someone help about this or someone suggest. is it possible that i can delete specific data using textbox or else ?... 
Sorry for my bad english :D

```
  Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand


    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\ProjectBsit4B\Book1.xlsx ;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
    cn.Open()

    With cm
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "delete [gmail$] set [NAME]= '" & txtboxName3.Text & "', [DEPARTMENT]= '" & Cb3.Text & "', [NOTES]='" & txtboxNotes3.Text & "' Where [EMAIL]='" & txtboxEmail3.Text & "' "

        .ExecuteNonQuery()

    End With
```

Comment: That is a very odd DELETE query.  You might want to research the proper SQL syntax...and maybe look into SQL injection and SQL Parameters

Comment: `delete [gmail$] set [NAME] ...` => this is not a proper `DELETE` query syntax, since `SET` always pairs with `UPDATE`. Use delete query like this: `DELETE FROM [sheetname$] WHERE ...`.

Comment: i changed it but this is will getting error "Deleting data in a linked table is not supported by this ISAM".  
           
            .CommandText = "delete * from [gmail$] Where [NAME]= '" & txtboxName3.Text & "', [DEPARTMENT]= '" & Cb3.Text & "', [NOTES]='" & txtboxNotes3.Text & "'[EMAIL]='" & txtboxEmail3.Text & "' "

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete rows with OleDb on Excel:

> Although the Jet OLE DB Provider
>   allows you to insert and update
>   records in an Excel workbook, it does
>   not allow DELETE operations. If you
>   try to perform a DELETE operation on
>   one or more records, you receive the
>   following error message...

From [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3e984c70-996e-4a76-aa04-5a2c8bf94eaa/selectinsertupdatedelete-excel-2007-file-and-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

What you can do is to **update every cell in the row** you want to delete and set them **to `NULL`**

For the update, the query could be like this:

```
.CommandText = "update [gmail$] set [NAME]= '', [DEPARTMENT]= '', [NOTES]='' Where [EMAIL]='" & txtboxEmail3.Text & "' "
```